# Is it possible to embed a login page with cookie and localstorage in iframe?

Tags: javascript, security, iframe

I have many websites: www.a.com & www.b.com & www.c.com & ... etc

And a user system, https://www.my-login.com/

I create many iframes like `<iframe src="https://www.my-login.com/embed.html" />` on all pages.

The login logic in `my-login.com/embed.html` is:

1. check if user already login by a cookie (domain=`my-login.com`)
2. if not, show login page, user can login, everything will done with a ajax request, then set a cookie on `my-login.com`, remember user already login.
3. if user already login, notify the parent pages with
   `window.parent.postMessage({ msg: 'userlogin', user: xxxx }), 'www.a.com')`

the parent page will get the user information asynchronously.

this works well before, but recently chrome blocked "3rd party cookies and data", so the 1st step failed, user must login everytime.

Is there any workaround without require users config their browser?

Comment: Why can't you use localstorage?

Answer (score 0):

finally I found that this is a update only on google chrome, it reject any "3-rd party data" by default on recent release.

no way to resolve.